# "TeX capacity exceeded" error when converting markdown to PDF using XeLaTeX with russian language

Tags: xetex, pdf, pandoc, markdown, russian

I've installed `pandoc` and `texlive-full` packages on recent Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit to convert markdown files with russian language to PDF.

Everything works fine when I run the following command:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --toc --chapters -V mainfont="Ubuntu" -f markdown -o test.pdf test.md
```

But in order to have russian language also in table of contents, in pictures' descriptions and etc I specify `lang` variable like this:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --toc --chapters -V mainfont="Ubuntu" -V lang="russian" -f markdown -o test.pdf test.md
```

and execution ends with the following message:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<inserted text> 
                -1
l.61 \tableofcontents
```

Everything works again if I specify another language, e.g. `french` or `dutch`:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --toc --chapters -V mainfont="Ubuntu" -V lang="french" -f markdown -o test.pdf test.md
```

It doesn't matter what contents of `test.md` are. They could be a simple text file:

```
# Первая глава

Текст первой главы.

# Вторая глава

Текст второй главы.

# Третья глава

Текст третьей главы.
```

I use default latex template:

```
pandoc -D latex > mytemplate.tex
```

and guess that something goes wrong when main language is set:

```
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{$mainlang$}
\else
    \usepackage[$lang$]{babel}
\fi
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? Unfortunately, I was unable to find workaround to fix the problem. As I can see there is a lot of issues that may cause this error. I'm absolute beginner in pandoc, TeX and all related things so any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Tried on Windows 7 Professional 32bit using [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) as [recommended by pandoc documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) specifying `-V mainfont="Times New Roman"` for font and got exactly the same error...

Comment: The culprit seems to be the presence of `Scale=MatchLowercase` in the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to reduce to this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

which aborts with

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   {
```

If the `Scale=MatchLowercase` option is removed, the document compiles. If I save the LaTeX file from your test with

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --toc --chapters -V mainfont="Linux Libertine O" -V lang="russian" -f markdown -w latex -s test.md > test.tex
```

and then remove the option, running XeLaTeX on `test.tex` is successful.

This is quite probably a bug in the Russian module for Polyglossia.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be connected to the Cyrillic font families not being properly selected. More like a side-effect than a bug, if you ask me.

Adding the following two definitions to my template, actually helps me to solve the issue without removing the currently default `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}`:

`% Define the main Cyrillic font:
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Your Font Here}
% Set the monospace Cyrillic font:
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Your Mono Font Here}`

Comment: I've also submitted a PR to pandoc that should fix the issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/pull/198